# Multer is storing in local AppData and not in specified directory

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using Multer with my MEAN2 stack and I have got file uploading working fine through ng2-uploader.

But I am trying to upload it to the server so i can then parse the csv file to json, but that is not the issue.

The file uploads fine ... but it uploads it to `AppData\Local\Temp`, here is the file information once uploaded:

```
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'sfgsgsfrfs.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
    filename: 'z83yrcprp4m8azfflxr.jpg',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\z83yrcprp4m8azfflxr.jpg',
    size: 120850 } ]
```

and here is my code that I am using to store the file:

```
const upload = multer({
    dest: './server/uploads/',
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
            cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
        }
    })
});

router.route('/upload').post(upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.json(req.files.map(file => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        return {
            originalName: file.originalname,
            filename: file.filename
        }
    }));
});
```

Any idea why it is doing so?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: @mscdex but then it has to be altered every time its in different place for people, with './server/uploads' it should be fine???, but it just ignores the 'dest' value, is it bercause fof multer.diskStorage ??

Comment: That was meant as a test to see if it would help any. If the path wasn't being resolved properly for whatever reason, you could use `__dirname` to help generate the absolute path (relative to the script file directory).

Comment: @mscdex ah okay i see, and i changed the dest to : `dest: __dirname + '/server/uploads/',` 
and then i console.logged the __dirname and req.files to make sure its working aswell, and this is the result: `C:\Users\Jezyk\Desktop\Feedbacker
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'freelance pay.txt',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'text/plain',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
    filename: '8cqvf7nn8v4e6401kyb9.txt',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\8cqvf7nn8v4e6401kyb9.txt',
    size: 104 } ]`

Comment: What version of multer are you using?

Comment: @mscdex     `"multer": "^1.2.0",` the latest release, only installed yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `destination` callback if using an explicit, configured storage instance:

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, __dirname + '/server/uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: still through the error, i seem to have got it working by getting rid of multer.diskStorage and just have this code:
`const upload = multer({
 dest: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, path.join(__dirname + '/server/uploads'))
 },
 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
  cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
 }
});`

but now it is generating the filename without the extension :S `    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads\\2a7c9594a1be1150512b53de5da707ab',`

Comment: should i just stick to using the file.originalname for saving the file, instead of generating random name? i.e. `cb(null, file.originalname)` for the filename section ? EDIT: saying that i done that and it still is generating random name for file without ext :S

Comment: You're probably better off not using any part of the original filename, if for no other reason than security purposes. Also, it's possible that the file type (and mime type) does not match the file extension, so there's even less sense in keep it around (although you could inspect the file contents with something like the `mmmagic` module to try and verify the file format if you need that).

Comment: i tweeked a few bits of your code and its working now, i am using path.joihn on __dirname and '/server/uploads' and got rid of => and works fine now!